# Woocommerce I am looking for billing address and order-received email hooks

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have to make two customization on my woocommerce site.

I need to know two main hooks. Someone out there please help me out!

1. Show custom field values to billing address on order-received page.(I added custom fields on checkout page.)
2. Need to include these values to customers' order-received email, too.

Thanks for stopping by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> To show custom field in order-received page you have to use
>   [`woocommerce_thankyou`](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_thankyou/) hook.

Here is the code:

```
// define the woocommerce_thankyou callback 
function action_woocommerce_thankyou($order_id)
{
    $my_custom_field = get_post_meta($order_id, '_billing_my_field', TRUE);
}

// add the action 
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'action_woocommerce_thankyou', 10, 1);
```

---

**UPDARED** This section after post author comment

> To add custom billing fields in WooCommerce email you have to use
>   [`woocommerce_email_customer_details`](http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_email_customer_details/) hook; this will be displayed just 
>   before the customer details.

Here is the code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_email_customer_details', 'custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields', 10, 3);

function custom_woocommerce_email_order_meta_fields($order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text)
{
    $_billing_my_field = get_post_meta($order->id, '_billing_my_field', true);
    if ($plain_text)
    {
        echo 'My field is ' . $_billing_my_field;
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<p>My field is  ' . $_billing_my_field . '</p>';
    }
}
```

*All code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

---

Please Note:

- *I have assuming that you have added a custom billing fields as `$fields['billing']['billing_my_field']` using [`woocommerce_checkout_fields`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/#section-3) hook.*
- *All the codes are tested and fully functional.*

Comment: Thanks @Raunak Gupta! First part did worked. But for the second half, I want it to show up inside customer detail section. Then I searched with google I found this https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Emails.html#101-125 . I guess I have to modify or filter? `public function customer_details()`, how can do that?

Comment: Welcome, if it helps then please accept my answer and upvote it.

Comment: I have update my answer please have a look, and yes we need `woocommerce_email_customer_details` hook to add custom fields in customer details section.

Comment: Thanks again for such a quick tip! It worked fine!! I changed filter priority to 20 so that custom fields value shows up under the regular customer detail :)